# QGIS Rule-Based Labeling: Can you Load a label style

Tags: qgis, labeling, qgis-3

QGIS 3.2

I want to use Rule-Based Labeling and load a label style to those features. Whenever I try to load a style it defaults to single based labeling and I can't find a style button in the rule based dialog box.

Is it possible to Load a label style into Rule Based Labeling in QGIS 3.2?

Comment: Layer style includes label settings, so when you load a style it should also load all of the label settings.

Comment: What happens if you paste a style onto a layer with rule-based labeling already set up? Does it overwrite the existing label rules?

Answer (score 3):

Layer style includes label settings, so when you load a style it *should* also load all of the label settings

**However, there's an open bug report for QGIS 3.2: [QGIS 3.2 Does not read label styling from QML file](https://issues.qgis.org/issues/19312).**

Until this bug is fixed, you'll have to revert to an older version. QGIS 2.18 should work as expected. Or re-do the Rule-Based Labeling manually every time you paste a style.